Struggling with 2 exercices related to "almost surely convergence"
I started measure theory 2 weeks ago and went into probabilities recently with books. I struggled with this one:
if $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X, \text{ then } Y = \sup |X_n| < \infty \text{ almost surely.}$
It would be easy if not almost surely  ( a function that converge is bounded...)
I saw that people often use Borel Cantelli lemma to demonstrate a.s convergence, but it seemed inappropriate here.
What do I have to say to counter this a.s ?
Thanks for your answers

But you don't need to show almost sure convergence. You need to show that $\sup |X_n|<\infty$ happens almost surely. This means you need to show that the event ${\sup|X_n|<\infty}$ has probability $1$. (given that the sequence $X_n$ converges in probability)

This is false. Let $X_n$ be independent random variables and suppose $X_n=0$ w.p. $1-\frac 1n$, $X_n=n$ w.p. $\frac  1n$. Then $X_n \to 0$ in probaility but $\sum P(X_n >n-1)=\infty$. Borel Cantelli Lemma shows that $X_n >n-1$ for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$ so $\sup |X_n |=\infty$ with probability $1$.
